# REDCap autofilling survey results into the following events

Tags: redcap

I'm using REDCap to collect contact information from healthcare facilities. I want to send out an annual invitation for facilities to review and update their contact information. So I'm wondering if there's a way to have survey results from event 1 auto filled into event 2. That way when they receive the survey invitation they can see their previous entries.
The instrument has over 200 fields and I have over 2000 records.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. If this is a longitudinal project, use `@DEFAULT='[previous-event-name][variable]'`. If you have repeating instruments, use `@DEFAULT='[variable][previous-instance]'`.
You might consider the case where most information doesn't change, and simply send them a reminder to go and check their information and update it if necessary. For this you could enable the survey as a 'save and return', and allow them to edit responses (survey settings). Then send an annual alert linking them to the single Facility Details survey.